# Saving pdf document from webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm navigating from webbrowser control to an url like this;
http://www.who.int/cancer/modules/Team%20building.pdf

It's shown in webbrowser control. What I want to do is to download this pdf file to computer. But I tried many ways;

```
Dim filepath As String
filepath = "D:\temp1.pdf"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(WebBrowserEx1.Url, filepath)
```

This one downloads a pdf but there is nothing in the file.

Also tried with

```
objWebClient.DownloadFile()
```

nothing changed.

I tried to show a save or print dialog;

```
WebBrowserEx1.ShowSaveAsDialog()
WebBrowserEx1.ShowPrintDialog()
```

but they didnt show any dialog. Maybe the last one is because it doesnt wait to load the the pdf into webbrowser completely.

When I try html files there is no problem to dowload, but in this **.pdf** file, I think I didn't manage to wait the file to be loaded as pdf into browser. This function(s);

```
 Private Sub WaitForPageLoad(ByVal adimno As String)
    If adimno = "1" Then
        AddHandler WebBrowserEx1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
        While Not pageReady
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        pageReady = False
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub PageWaiter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If WebBrowserEx1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        pageReady = True
        RemoveHandler WebBrowserEx1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    End If
End Sub
```

are not working for this situation. I mean it gets into infinite loop.

So anyone knows how to wait this to load pdf then save into computer.

Answer (score 0):

you could test the URL when document completed fires and if its .pdf, then do the following then navigate back, for example.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowserEx1.Navigate("http://www.who.int/cancer/modules/Team%20building.pdf")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowserEx1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowserEx1.DocumentCompleted

    If WebBrowserEx1.Url.ToString.Contains(".pdf") Then

        Using webClient = New WebClient()
            Dim bytes = webClient.DownloadData(WebBrowserEx1.Url.ToString) 'again variable here

            File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "TEST.pdf"), bytes) 'save to desktop or specialfolder. to list all the readily available user folders
        End Using

 'WebBrowserEx1.goback() 'could send browser back a page as well

    End If



End Sub
```

You will need to make the filename "TEST" as a variable instead of a static string or else you will overwrite the same file each time.  Perhaps:

```
 WebBrowserEx1.DocumentTitle.ToString & ".pdf"
```

instead, which would save the file as pdf named by the webpage title.  Only problem there is if the page contains illegal characters (that windows doesnt let you save with) it will throw an exception so that should be handled.

Comment: thanks but it fires DocumentCompleted event just once and it doest complete at that time. So, still, 0 byte of pdf is saved.

Comment: @Mtok document completed will fire only once (more if there are web frames, etc), it doesnt matter whether the pdf is loaded or not in the WBC, all its looking for is the URL ending with .pdf to pass to a new instance of webclient which takes the url and downloads from that url as a byte.  Is the page you are attempting to download on the internet? This worked fine with your provided example for me.

Comment: the url is not that one, i showed that url to show how the pdf is opened. I'm doing some login to a website (through webbrowser) after some pages i got to the pdf that is dynamically created (by a script) and at last I get the url like; http://uyg.sgk.gov.tr/EBorcuYoktur5510/PdfOlustur.pdf?rapor=PdfCok&turcode=2&ts=16.05.2013_16:18:11

So i need to download the pdf which is already in the webbrowser, not via url.

Comment: @Mtok The only thing I can think of is to change how IE handles the PDF MIME type and then try to catch the file on the WBC file download event. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459273/read-pdf-contents-using-webbrowser-control-in-c-sharp "Because IE embed whatever program is registered for the pdf file type on the user's client computer, there is no standard way you can access the document."

My Speculation: This would make sense because trying to stream/read the document is returning nothing, meaning the WBC is not trulyhandling the pdf, adobe is